# How to replace " " " with space

Tags: c#, string, replace

I am trying to replace double quotes with space but it's not working, says syntax error,

```
"'asd"asd', 'asdasda"sdsa'"    // This is the string pattern I am getting "somehow"
string b = a.Replace(""", " "));
```

Comment: Your original text doesn't contain any double-quotes anyway, so what are you trying to replace? (You can just escape it as `a.Replace("\"", " ")` but you need to be aware it won't do anything in this case.)

Comment: escape your quote. a.Replace("\"", " "));

Comment: "\"" should work for you

Comment: @JonSkeet this is just example, in my original code it has double quotes, but didn't thought thats relevant to put in question

Comment: It's relevant in terms of providing a useful example.

Comment: @JonSkeet I updated my question, but the pattern I am getting is too hard to explain but it got double quotes somehow. thanks

Comment: i found this page with info on escaping chars in C#: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/371232/Escaping-in-Csharp-characters-strings-string-forma and this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet to be fair to the op in order for them to post or use an example with a " in it they would probably already be aware of the escape character.

Comment: @NicholasKing: True, but in attempting to do so they'd realize that the problem is actually nothing to do with replacement, and everything to do with representing a double-quote in a string literal.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to escape the `"` with a backslash:

```
string b = a.Replace("\"", " ");
```

where `string a` is `bla bla " bla " bla bla`

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the `qoute`. Given you have had quotes, this is what will happen

```
string a = "\"asdasd\", \"asdasdasdsa\"";
string b = a.Replace("\"", " "); // b = " asdasd ,  asdasdasdsa "
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,
I think you are declaring the `string a` in a wrong way.
Normally in a declaration of a string, there should be a double quote in each end, like `string a = "..."`, and they won't be counted in the content of the string. If you want to include a double quote in the string, you should put a slash ahead of it, like: `string a = "I said, \"Thanks.\"".`
If you print a, you will get

> *I said, "Thanks."*

Secondly, the same problem.

```
string b = a.Replace("\"", " "));
```